# Manter focus ao clicar na div e desmanter ao clicar em elemento dentro da div

Tags: javascript, jquery

O título se resumo a dúvida, gostaria que ao clicar no input dentro do quadro perdesse o focus do campo de busca, obrigado desde já pela assistência no entendimento.

```js
     $('.quadro').click(function(){
  $('.input_busca').focus();
  });
```

```css
    .quadro{
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height:300px;
top:50px;
background: black;
color: white;
}
.elemento{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<input class='input_busca' type='text' autofocus/>

<div class='quadro'>

<input type='text' class='elemento'>

</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta ... seja mais clara possivel!

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta, mas já tentou usar o `blur()`?

Comment: Oi para vocês mal a demora tive que alterar a senha pois não lembrava... Se vocês observarem quando é clicado em qualquer lugar div class='quadro' o focus volta para o input pré-determinado fora da div pelo jquery, mas quando clica no input dentro da div class='quadro' não gostaria que o focus fosse pra lá, estou iniciando em jQuery não sei como diferenciar e resolver isso

Comment: É verdade o blur() deve resolver, farei testes obg

Answer (score 0):

É o seu código código JavaScript que está jogando o focus de volta para o campo de busca. Se você remover ele, terá o resultado que você descreveu:

```css
    .quadro{
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height:300px;
top:50px;
background: black;
color: white;
}
.elemento{
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<input class='input_busca' type='text' autofocus/>

<div class='quadro'>

<input type='text' class='elemento'>

</div>
```